error: subprocess-exited-with-error, Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully while installing python-poppler
I've been trying to install poppler but keep running into errors related to metadata pyproject.toml
C:\Users\G>pip install python-poppler
Collecting python-poppler
  Using cached python_poppler-0.4.1.tar.gz (138 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a\.mesonpy-6mp57599 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a\.mesonpy-6mp57599\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a
      Build dir: C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a\.mesonpy-6mp57599
      Build type: native build
      Project name: python-poppler
      Project version: 0.4.1

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler cl cannot compile programs.

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcfacjas\python-poppler_b1b4f45d34114e6198bd1fb702a5536a\.mesonpy-6mp57599\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried wheel update, build updates, installed Visual studio build tools with C++ development and even tried to manually fetch the tar.az and install it, tried choco install poppler but same issue, manually downloaded file, extracted, put in the path variables, still unable to use it. I also tried looking for the log details .txt file mentioned in the above error, but it doesn't exist, pip upgrade, checked the python version too, it's 3.12 64 bit, also tried to mkdir and cmake it into running but alas, help. I use jupyter notebook, i got the same error on admin cmd too.
